# Nothing is printed from ListView.Builder into the emulator while initState shows that My list has 2 elements

Tags: visual-studio, flutter, listview, flutter-test, flutter-listview

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyHomePage());
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<String> ListSearch = [];
  Future getData() async {
    var data = await http.get('http://10.0.2.2/DBCON/search.php');
    var databody = jsonDecode(data.body);
    for (int i = 0; i < databody.length; i++) {
      ListSearch.add(databody[i]['NAME']);
    }
    print(ListSearch);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getData();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('ss'),
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: ListSearch.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Column(
              children: [
                Text(ListSearch[index]),
                Text(ListSearch.length.toString()),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am trying to bring some data from localhost and show them in my app in the emulator, but the emulator shows nothing and initState gives an output of 2 elements in ListSearch List,
Can someone tell me why nothing is printed and how to fix that?

[This is the output in the emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIdrQ.png)

[and this is the output in the initState in debug console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAnHx.png)

Comment: add a `then` callback to `getData()` with setState or use FutueBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy paste run full code below 
Demo code has 3 seconds delay to simulate network delay 
You can use `bool isLoading` to control when `isLoading` show `CircularProgressIndicator()`, when loading finish show `ListView`
code snippet

```
bool isLoading = true;
Future getData() async {
    ...
    print(ListSearch);

    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });
...
body: isLoading
            ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
            : ListView.builder(
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyHomePage());
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<String> ListSearch = [];
  bool isLoading = true;
  Future getData() async {
    //var data = await http.get('http://10.0.2.2/DBCON/search.php');
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () {});
    String jsonString = '''
    [
      {"NAME": "Samsung A30"},
      {"NAME": "Samsung Note20"}
    ]
    ''';

    http.Response data = http.Response(jsonString, 200);
    var databody = jsonDecode(data.body);
    for (int i = 0; i < databody.length; i++) {
      ListSearch.add(databody[i]['NAME']);
    }
    print(ListSearch);

    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getData();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('ss'),
        ),
        body: isLoading
            ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
            : ListView.builder(
                itemCount: ListSearch.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(ListSearch[index]),
                      Text(ListSearch.length.toString()),
                    ],
                  );
                },
              ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```